# How to block folder access to ftp with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

here is a script for apache to disable folder access via browser:

```
   ## no access to this folder

# Apache 2.4
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>

# Apache 2.2
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
Options -Indexes
```

But it does not work: `https://doboda.com/wp-content/uploads/movies/`

How can i block it?

Comment: FTP? Do you mean the directory listing that Apache generates (showing the list of files and folders)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not FTP. This is the **directory listing** option. You can disable it by adding this line to `.htaccess`:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: i added this but it doesnot work:  https://doboda.com/wp-content/uploads/kinos/2018/

Comment: Where did you place the .htaccess file? inside the `uploads` directory?

Comment: I'm not sure why it's not working. It is possible (but unlikely) that the hosting service disabled overriding that option. Try moving the `Options -indexes` to the top of the .htaccess file. Also, what are the file permissions for .htaccess?

Comment: i use vps and i can change overwrite url, but yes i put it to the top of the file. The file is located in https://doboda.com/wp-content/uploads/movies/.  and i want to blokc eveyr acces in this folder and contain folers https://doboda.com/wp-content/uploads/movies/

Comment: What are the file permissions for `.htaccess`?

Comment: the permission is 644

Comment: and parent folder has 0755, i want to block any access to this folder

Comment: @MarMir I can't think of any reason why it does not work. Check Apache's logs to see if it shows any errors processing the `.htaccess` file. One solution is to place an empty `index.html` file in the directory you want to prevent directory listing in. This will show an empty page when the folder is accessed.

Comment: that is good idea but can anyone then know which mp4 files i use in this folder? with program winhttrack can anyone get my mp4 files?

Comment: that is apache error log: https://b.radikal.ru/b11/2006/64/b59c10757078.png

Comment: If the directory listing is not shown (i.e. you have a blank page instead), it is not possible for anyone to know what files are in that directory.

Comment: The log file is probably in `/var/log/apache2/error.log` ... Can you share the output of `sudo tail -50 /var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: hjhjh hj hj hj hj hj hj

Comment: i can not input a image here, how can i contact u and send the image?